# Confused of what really are optionsValue and value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using knockout js 3.2 , I have basic confusion on how select binding works

```
<select data-bind="options: choices,
            optionstext: 'DisplayName' ,
            optionsvalue :'Id' ,
            value:id,
            optionscaption :'Select...'"></select>
```

In the above example if we have an object of type

```
var choices = [
        { id: 'M', DisplayName: "Male" },
        { id: 'F', DisplayName: "Female" }        
    ];
```

What is the differences and uses of value and optionsvalue?Could some one help out.

Comment: There are some good examples in the documentation http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html. Have you read them?

Answer (score 2):

The `value` parameter tells the binding the name of the observable to set with the selected value of the select. So in your example, a little bit modified

```
var choices = [
    { id: 'M', DisplayName: "Male" },
    { id: 'F', DisplayName: "Female" }        
];
```

With the binding:

```
<select data-bind="options: choices,
        optionstext: 'DisplayName' ,
        value: selectedChoice,
        optionscaption :'Select...'"></select>
```

This binding assumes that your viewModel (the object that contains the `choices` array) also contains an object (observable) called `selectedChoice` which will contain either `{ id: 'M', DisplayName: "Male" }` or `{ id: 'F', DisplayName: "Female"}`.

Now, let's add in the `optionsValue` binding, which tells the binding which property of the selected option to put into the selected `value` binding. So let's add that in (note that it is case sensitive, since it's referencing a javascript object property, which are case sensitive:

```
<select data-bind="options: choices,
        optionstext: 'DisplayName' ,
        value: selectedChoice,
        optionsValue: 'id',
        optionscaption :'Select...'"></select>
```

Now, when user selects a choice from the select element, `selectedChoice` will not contain the entire choice object, but rather, just the `id` property. So, `selectedChoice` will either be `'F'` or `'M'`.

Put more simply `optionsValue: 'id'` means "set the selected value to the `id` property of the selected item" and `value: selectedChoice` means "store the selected item in the `selectedChoice` observable.

```js
vm = {
  choices: [ { id: 'M', DisplayName: 'Male' }, { id: 'F', DisplayName: 'Female' } ],
  selectedChoice1: ko.observable(),
  selectedChoice2: ko.observable()
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
Using optionsValue='id':
<select data-bind="options: choices, value: selectedChoice1, optionsText: 'DisplayName', optionsValue: 'id'"></select>
Selected Option: <span data-bind="text: selectedChoice1"></span>
<br/>
Without optionsValue:
<select data-bind="options: choices, value: selectedChoice2, optionsText: 'DisplayName'"></select>
Selected Option: <span data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(selectedChoice2())"></span>
```

Comment: thanks http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html could not explain this in such clear way!